# How to get number of concurrent sessions and average response latency in cowboy?

Tags: erlang, cowboy

I have a rather simple web app built with on top of cowboy http server. What is the right way to measure miscellaneous health parameters in real-time, like 1, 5 and 10 minute averages of connections and response latency, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `boundary/folsom` or `feuerlabs/exometer` for this. There is no built-in solution, but the two mentioned applications can be used to measure/instrument Erlang systems in general. They are highly recommended.